# Outlier detection depending on group

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, data-cleaning, outliers

I have a dataset (*new_america*) like this:

```
   |  PRICE |   CITY   |    STATE      |
   |--------|--------- |---------------|
   | 950000 | Dorado   | Puerto Rico   |
   | 785442 | Amherst  | Massachusetts |
   | 547478 | Chicopee | Massachusetts |
   | 400000 | Hamden   | Connecticut   |
```

And +300,00 extra rows reporting house prices in different cities and states.
I run the follwing R code:

```
new_america %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = state, y = price, fill = state)) +
      geom_boxplot()
```

[image]
and realized the df is full of outliers.
I was trying to compare, and eventually detect, outliers based on the state (or even the city) the apartment  is located in, in order not to compare states that have different price ranges (I reckon it wouldn't be correct to compare Vermont prices with New York prices)

How can I solve it?

Comment: This isn't at all a programming question. What an "outlier" is and what you should do with it is all theoretical. What's even the point of comparing Vermont prices to New York prices? What does "New York prices" mean if you exclude NYC? If your data is "full of outliers", are they really outliers?

Comment: You could try asking on stats.stackexchange, but they won't be able to help you either unless you can be a lot more specific. What are your goals? What method(s) do you plan to use? Is your data the price of individual houses, or is it already aggregated somehow? Have you looked at examples of similar analyses? (There's a reason *median home value* not *average home value* is a commonly reported statistic...)

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you have several dots plotted as "outliers" in a boxplot, you have to question if this is an accurate representation of the data distribution's extreme values. Consider the `diamonds` dataset. When making boxplots for cuts of diamonds by price, you get something fairly similar:

```
#### Load Library ####
library(tidyverse)

#### Boxplot ####
diamonds %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=cut,
             y=price))+
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Now if you were to make a scatterplot of the same data:

```
#### Scatterplot ####
diamonds %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=cut,
             y=price))+
  geom_point(position = "jitter")
```

It would look like this:

[image]

You can see now that these values aren't really problematic outliers. While the distribution is weighted more heavily towards the bottom of the prices, there are several high price items in this data getting flagged as outliers in the boxplot. If you were to drop all of these values, you would lose a substantial amount of data, and with it, a lot of valuable insights into diamond prices by cut.

To illustrate this further, we can look for all the outliers for price based on the grouping for the diamond cuts with this code:

```
#### Find Outliers ####
library(rstatix)

diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  mutate(outlier_price = is_outlier(price)) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(outlier_price == "TRUE") %>% 
  summarise(sum_outlier = n())
```

You will find another oddity here...despite having a more uniform distribution of values in the Ideal cut group, it has substantially more identified outliers:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 2
  cut       sum_outlier
  <ord>           <int>
1 Fair              148
2 Good              327
3 Very Good         731
4 Premium           755
5 Ideal            1627
```